# Unable to edit storyboard in Xcode 12 after IBAgent NSInternalInconsistencyException: Failed to create work interval

Tags: ios, xcode

I am unable to edit storyboard files in my xcode project.

I have tried cleaning my Derived Data and cleaning my project but it has had no effect.

In the IBAgent crash log I found this.

I get further errors in the designer "already shutdown" errors. I believe because of the IBAgent crash

Here is the crash log:

```
Process:               IBAgent-iOS [81085]
Path:                  /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/Library/Xcode/Overlays/IBAgent-iOS
Identifier:            IBAgent-iOS
Version:               12.0.1 (17125)
Code Type:             X86-64 (Native)
Parent Process:        launchd_sim [81011]
Responsible:           SimulatorTrampoline [1320]
User ID:               501

Date/Time:             2020-10-07 12:38:24.736 -0400
OS Version:            Mac OS X 10.15.6 (19G2021)
Report Version:        12
Anonymous UUID:        B35CBFA6-5A9D-0F38-AAF9-43DECA2C829D


Time Awake Since Boot: 440000 seconds

System Integrity Protection: enabled

Crashed Thread:        0  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread

Exception Type:        EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes:       0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
Exception Note:        EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY

Application Specific Information:
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Failed to create work interval'
terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
abort() called
CoreSimulator 732.17 - Device: iPhone Xʀ (4069A6FF-6A3D-4066-A9E5-2871B5CF6183) - Runtime: iOS 14.0 (18A372) - DeviceType: iPhone Xʀ

Application Specific Backtrace 1:
0   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff2043a126 __exceptionPreprocess + 242
1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x00007fff20177f78 objc_exception_throw + 48
2   UIKitCore                           0x00007fff24a5fcb7 _UIQOSProcessingEnd + 0
3   UIKitCore                           0x00007fff24a5faf9 _UIQOSProcessingBegin + 309
4   UIKitCore                           0x00007fff2404fd51 -[_UISceneDisplayLink _displayLinkTick:] + 98
5   QuartzCore                          0x00007fff278e732d _ZN2CA7Display11DisplayLink14dispatch_itemsEyyy + 755
6   QuartzCore                          0x00007fff279cb99c _ZL22display_timer_callbackP12__CFMachPortPvlS1_ + 639
7   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff2037670c __CFMachPortPerform + 157
8   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff203a913d __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE1_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 41
9   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff203a84de __CFRunLoopDoSource1 + 614
10  CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff203a29ba __CFRunLoopRun + 2353
11  CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff203a1b9e CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 567
12  Foundation                          0x00007fff20846e61 -[NSRunLoop(NSRunLoop) runMode:beforeDate:] + 209
13  IBFoundation                        0x000000010c137bf0 -[IBAbstractPlatformTool startServingReceiveChannel:] + 399
14  IBFoundation                        0x000000010c137e56 -[IBAbstractPlatformTool startServingWriteDescriptor:readDescriptor:] + 111
15  IBFoundation                        0x000000010c138b40 +[IBAbstractPlatformTool main] + 1237
16  IBAgent-iOS                         0x000000010bba295f main + 34
17  libdyld.dylib                       0x00007fff20257415 start + 1

Thread 0 Crashed:: Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff5dca633a __pthread_kill + 10
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff5dcdbe60 pthread_kill + 430
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff200fabd4 abort + 120
3   libc++abi.dylib                 0x00007fff20250818 abort_message + 231
4   libc++abi.dylib                 0x00007fff20241e7d demangling_terminate_handler() + 266
5   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x00007fff201781d1 _objc_terminate() + 96
6   libc++abi.dylib                 0x00007fff2024fc47 std::__terminate(void (*)()) + 8
7   libc++abi.dylib                 0x00007fff202525b6 __cxa_rethrow + 99
8   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x00007fff2017810c objc_exception_rethrow + 37
9   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff203a1cc4 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 861
10  com.apple.Foundation            0x00007fff20846e61 -[NSRunLoop(NSRunLoop) runMode:beforeDate:] + 209
11  com.apple.dt.IBFoundation       0x000000010c137bf0 -[IBAbstractPlatformTool startServingReceiveChannel:] + 399
12  com.apple.dt.IBFoundation       0x000000010c137e56 -[IBAbstractPlatformTool startServingWriteDescriptor:readDescriptor:] + 111
13  com.apple.dt.IBFoundation       0x000000010c138b40 +[IBAbstractPlatformTool main] + 1237
14  IBAgent-iOS                     0x000000010bba295f main + 34
15  libdyld.dylib                   0x00007fff20257415 start + 1
```

Answer (score 0):

This happened when I upgraded to Xcode 13.0.

I couldn't find much help on the subject, but from trial and error, the solution for my situation seemed to be:

```
open ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/iOS\ DeviceSupport
rm -rf <VERSION>
```

I did this for every version expect the latest version (in this case `15.0.2 (19A404)`)